# Chart X axis not ploting data as per dataset when need to show duplicate values

Tags: ios, swift, charts

Issue is :
[Image to understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwmTO.png) :: Described below

The issue is, it is ploting up and down at same X value. Instead of that, i want to display both X values in left right. Basically want X values based on Dataset's X values.

Tried various ways :

Way 1:

`lineView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: arrStrDates)` // arrStrDates is X Axis label values

Way 2:

Tried by creating custom formatter :

```
class CustomLabelsAxisValueFormatter : NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
    
    var labels: [String] = []
    
    func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        
        let count = self.labels.count
        
        guard let axis = axis, count > 0 else {
            
            return ""
        }
        
        let factor = axis.axisMaximum / Double(count)
        
        let index = Int((value / factor).rounded())
        
        if index >= 0 && index < count {
            
            return self.labels[index]
        }
        
        return ""
    }
}

let formatter = CustomLabelsAxisValueFormatter()

formatter.labels = xVals

chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = formatter
```

Way 3 :

```
lineView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
lineView.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

This is how adding into datasets:

```
let data = LineChartData()
data.dataSets.append(dataset1)
data.dataSets.append(dataset2)
chartView.data = data
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, could you explain what your x values are for the two y values that gets plotted above each other? Are you saying they are different even though they are treated as equal?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson,

Dataset value is as below.

[Aug 19, 110]
[Aug 14, 120]
[Aug 14, 135]
[Aug 10, 110]….


What I am expecting in X axis, it should plot only dates which is in array. 19,14,14,10 and so on.. issue is currently it is plotting 19,17,16,14,12,10,8(Which you can see in question image) which is automatically by chart itself. I want to plot x axis as per dataset(Array) only.[Based on date only]

Comment: Maybe your dataset should contain an index (Int) instead of the date string as x value and then you use that index to get the correct label.